# Subfolder in the Nuxt store is messing with the modules

Tags: typescript, vuex, nuxt.js, vuex-modules

Trying to create a project in Nuxt and typescript. However the documentation it's very poor and I hit a lot of issues. Somehow was able to solve most of them, but stacked on an issue with the **store**. Based on the Nuxt documentation every file inside the store directory is transformed to a module.

To organize better my project I decided to add a subfolder inside **store** folder. However after this change my components are having issues with calling *Mutation*, *Action* and getting values from the store/module.

When I'm checking the Developer Console in Vue Tab (Vuex) I can see that my State and getters have the subfolder name before the module.
[image]

In case that I decide to put every new module/store inside the **store** folder everything is working absolutely fine.

I'm using `vuex-module-decorators` package for my modules as in my opinion it improves readability of the code and simplify the process.

The error which I'm getting is:

```
[vuex] unknown action type: applicationStage/initializeArticles
[vuex] unknown mutation type: applicationStage/addArticle
```

So the questions are:

1. Am I doing something wrong?
2. Can I have a subfolder inside the **store** folder and how to register the module in a way to skip the subfolder name when it's creating the module?

My **store** folder structure

```
-store
--index.ts
--progress
---applicationStage.ts
```

./store/progress/applicationStage.ts

```
import {
  Module,
  Action,
  VuexModule,
  Mutation,
  MutationAction
} from "vuex-module-decorators";

interface Article {
  title: string;
  body: string;
  published: boolean;
  meta: {
    [key: string]: string;
  };
}

const articles = [
  {
    title: "Hello World!",
    body: "This is a sample article.",
    published: true,
    meta: {}
  },
  {
    title: "My writing career continues!",
    body: `...but I've run out of things to say.`,
    published: false,
    meta: {}
  }
];

@Module({
  name: "applicationStage",
  stateFactory: true,
  namespaced: true
})
export default class ApplicationStageModule extends VuexModule {
  articles: Article[] = [
    {
      title: "Initial article",
      body:
        "This is the starting point, before we initialize the article store.",
      published: true,
      meta: {}
    }
  ];

  get allArticles() {
    return this.articles;
  }

  get publishedArticles() {
    return this.articles.filter(article => article.published);
  }

  @MutationAction({ mutate: ["articles"] })
  async initializeArticles() {
    return { articles };
  }

  @Mutation
  addArticle() {
    this.articles.push({
      title: "Hello World 2!",
      body: "This is a sample article 2.",
      published: true,
      meta: {}
    });
  }
}
```

./components/HelloWorld.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    {{ message }}
    <h2>Published articles</h2>
    <article v-for="article in articleList" :key="article.title">
      <h3 v-text="article.title"/>
      <div v-text="article.body"/>
    </article>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue } from "vue-property-decorator";
import { getModule } from "vuex-module-decorators";
import ApplicationStageModule from "../store/progress/applicationStage";

@Component
export default class HelloWorld extends Vue {
  message: string = "Hello world !";
  articleStore = getModule(ApplicationStageModule, this.$store);
  articleList: any[] = [
    {
      title: "Initial article",
      body:
        "This is the starting point, before we initialize the article store.",
      published: true,
      meta: {}
    }
  ];

  mounted() {
    this.articleStore.initializeArticles();  // ERROR LINE
    this.articleStore.addArticle();   // ERROR LINE
    this.updateArticles();
  }

  public updateArticles() {
    this.articleList = this.articleStore.allArticles;
  }
}
</script>
```

I have created a sandbox where my issue can be replicated https://codesandbox.io/s/723xyzl60j

Comment: you have asked that question a year ago, but did you find any answer? with `namespace` you lose typesafety, which is definetly not what I want...

Answer (score -1):

You should use `const applicationStage = namespace("progress/applicationStage/");` instead of `getModule(...)`.
When `stateFactory` is `true` the `module` is "autoloaded".
You might need to inject the store directly in the `decorator` too.
Huh, and when you use `stateFactory`, `namespaced` option is useless because it will be **namespaced** due to `stateFactory` **being** `true`.